# Use of "RelationalEntityTypeBuilderExtensions.ToTable" not compiling even though including the assembly

Tags: c#-8.0, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have the following code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace JobAssist.Services.ResumeBankMgmt.Infrastructure.EntityConfigurations
{
    /// <summary>
    /// DBContext Configuration for ClientRequest
    /// </summary>
    internal class ClientRequestEntityTypeConfiguration
        : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ClientRequest>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Configuration of entity Client Request
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="requestConfiguration">ClientRequest</param>
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ClientRequest> requestConfiguration)
        {
            requestConfiguration.ToTable("resumebankrequests", ResumeBankContext.DEFAULT_SCHEMA);
            requestConfiguration.HasKey(cr => cr.Id);
            requestConfiguration.Property(cr => cr.Name).IsRequired();
            requestConfiguration.Property(cr => cr.Time).IsRequired();
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile this I get this error:

"Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'EntityTypeBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ToTable' and no accessible extension method 'ToTable' accepting a first argument of type 'EntityTypeBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

My project file is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <StartupObject />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\..\..\..\.editorconfig" Link=".editorconfig" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="3.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for RelationalEntityTypeBuilderExtensions.ToTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypebuilderextensions.totable?view=efcore-3.1) references `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll` as the assembly implementing this extension method, so it looks like you need to include the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/) NuGet.

Comment: How did you figure that out?

Comment: @MikeLenart I've updated my answer with more information about how I found which NuGet to include.